# CGI script - how to create confirmation box pop up?

Tags: javascript, perl, cgi

I am running a CGI script to block address in security device (Using wget command) and I'd like have a confirmation box pop up during loading and ask a yes/no question, if the answer is no -exit  and if the answer is yes continue to block the address.  Any ideas?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI qw(:standart escapeHTML);
use CGI qw(:param);
use LWP::Simple;
$pass ='xxxxxx';
$rip = param('ip');
$addr=$ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'};
print "Content-type: text/html \n\n";
print "<html>";
print "<head> <title>Block IP </title></head>";
print "<body>";

if($rip=~m/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/)
{
  system("wget \'https://x.x.x.x/policy/test?
  deviceuser=user1&passd=$password&ip=$rip&policy=Quar_1D\' -O \/dev\/null --no-
  check-certificate 2>&1 | grep response -A 3");
  print "<script type='text/javascript'>";
}
else 
{
  if(!$rip)
  {
    print '<script type=\'text/javascript\'>
    var gip=prompt(\'enter an ip  to block\',\'\');
    if (!gip) {
        window.location=\'http://x.x.x.x/cgi-bin/block.cgi\';
    } else {
        window.location="http://x.x.x.x/cgi-bin/block_tp.cgi?ip="+gip;
    }';
  }
}
print "</script></body></html>";
```

Comment: Do you need an actual popup or confirmation yes/no in Perl?

Comment: you've already got that ugly javascript fake-form thing going on - why not do the confirmation in javascript too?

Comment: Can you send an example? The user has to click Yes or No using the computer mouse.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_confirm2

Comment: I have some issue with the syntax. the script ignores from the javascript.
Can you help with the syntax?

Answer (score 4):

This question shows a fundamental misunderstanding of how an HTTP interaction works. HTTP is a stateless protocol. The client (probably a browser) sends a request and the server sends a response. The next request/response cycle has no connection to the previous one unless the developer does something to store information about the state. With simple CGI mechanisms you cannot get halfway through processing a request and then stop to ask the user for more information.

What you want can probably possible by writing Javascript and making Ajax requests to the web server. But given your level of knowledge of web development, I strongly recommend you either employ a programmer or spend a year or so working your way up to this.

In addition, there are some get strange things going on in your CGI program.

- You use `-w` instead of the more modern `use warnings`.
- You don't have `use strict` (and, therefore, you don't declare any of your variables).
- You load the CGI module twice.
- You have spelled `:standard` wrong (but you don't use any of the standard functions anyway).
- You explicitly load `escapeHTML` but never make use of it.
- You load LWP::Simple but then ignore it in favour of shelling out to `wget` instead.
- You do nothing at all with the results from your call to `wget`.
- You escape quote characters unnecessarily.